# Error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stddef.h': No such file or directory

Tags: qtcreator, qt

ОС: win 7 64

Установил MS VS 2012 32bit и четвертый апдейт для него, потом winsdk 7.1 и в конце Qt 5.2.1 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2012, 541 MB)(хотя в About Qt Creator написано "Based on Qt 5.2.1 (MSVC 2010, 32-bit)).

Создаю стандартный Qt Widgets Application. При компиляции такая ошибка:

[image: Imgur]

Настройки Qt:

[image: Imgur]

Что-то там с cl.exe. Добавил в переменную Path путь C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin.

После создания проекта появляется ошибка:

> Запуск программы невозможен, так как
>   на компьютере отсутствует
>   mspdb110.dll. Попробуйте
>   переустановить программу.

Ошибка при компиляции почти та же самая:

[image: Imgur]

Добавил в Path путь к mspdb110.dll C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE

Ошибка с mspdb110.dll пропала, но при компиляции

> error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stddef.h': No such file or directory

Что-то я запутался с этим Qt. Раньше нормально работал из коробки.

Comment: Поставьте с MinGW, там проблем не будет скорее всего.

Comment: Может я и зря с этим лезу, но зачем с QtCreator использовать компилятор от студии? MinGW имеет ряд преимуществ. ИМХО, студия - отличная IDE с шикарным отладчиком, MFC (господи, прости!) там всякое, но для сферического программирования в вакууме лучше выбрать GCC (на виндах известен как MinGW).

Comment: С студией нормально раньше работало, поэтому не парился особо. Сейчас не знаю, что не так. Попробую MinGW.